# PHP date to current date of the day

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

How do i make this the current day today. my calendar date is not the same with the days.

Source code:

```
<div class="box-header well" data-original-title>
  <h2><i class="icon-user"></i> Monday
    <?php if(date('l', strtotime(date("now"))) == 'Monday'): ?>
        (Today)
    <?php endif; ?>
  </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: You can reference http://tw1.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Take a look at DateTime http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 0):

You only need `if (date('l') == 'Monday')`. Without specifying the second parameter it defaults to the current time.